# Cannot reflect over assembly that shares a dependency of different version

Tags: c#, reflection, assembly.reflectiononly

Here's the scenario using *Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom*:

Both my assembly ***Inspected*** and my reflection Application ***Inspector*** reference Assembly ***Dependency***.

If ***Inspector*** references ***Dependency 1.0.0.0*** and ***Inspected*** references ***Dependency 1.1.0.0***, ***Inspector*** cannot reflect over any types or methods in ***Inspected*** that use a type from ***Dependency***. The moment such a type is hit i get:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not
>   load file or assembly 'Dependency,
>   Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's
>   manifest definition does not match the
>   assembly reference. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131040)

However, ***Inspector*** can reflect over ***Dependency 1.1.0.0*** itself just fine, so loading ***Dependency 1.1.0.0*** as *Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom* does work from an assembly that's already using ***Dependency 1.0.0.0***.

Here is the code i use to load an assembly and preload it's dependencies:

```
var assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyPath);
foreach (var assemblyName in assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()) {
  Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(assemblyName.FullName);
}
```

It's not an issue with ***Dependency 1.1.0.0*** not being resolved, as i've set a breakpoint in the foreach and confirmed it is loaded and also checked *AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyGetAssemblies()* for its presence. It's loaded alright. But when i then do *assembly.GetTypes()*, it dies.

Is there something i can do about this, or do i have to reflect over assemblies in a separate AppDomain and marshall the meta data back into the appdomain that has a reference to ***Dependency 1.0.0.0***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Customizing the .NET Framework Common Language Runtime](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780735619883/) , it is explained that Load and LoadFrom create separate "scopes" for loaded assemblies, which I guess explains the problem.
Something to try is to find the assemblies yourself and load them all with LoadFrom.

Have you tried handling the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event ?

Comment: I tried both AppDomain.AssemblyResolve and AppDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve and neither ever fired. I assume it's because it already has a different version loaded. I'll look at whether i can use only LoadFrom.

Comment: Turns out it was a matter of using LoadFrom for loading the dependents. My initial tests kept failing but for other reasons. all good now.

Comment: On second thought, it makes sense, as there are DLLs loaded by .NET itself, which is done with Load and not LoadFrom. So, the correct suggestion should have been to try and do without LoadFrom

Comment: The problem with Load was that the other version was already loaded, so somehow Load would not fail but not load it either, but by using LoadFrom it succeeded.

I actually fall back on Load if LoadFrom fails (so i can load GAC dependencies). It's just that Load gives me a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this problem 11 years after the original question. Solved it by applying the current AppDomain policy to the assembly being loaded by reflection:

```cs
Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ApplyPolicy(args.Name));
```

Note in the app.config for the running application you will need a redirect like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Some.Dependency" publicKeyToken="someToken" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```